# could you help to translate to English？ “我以为文学可以踏过所有误解和隔阂,没想过会有人冲它不止一次举起刀”

Tags: simplified-characters

“我以为文学可以踏过所有误解和隔阂,没想过会有人冲它不止一次举起刀”

Could anyone help me to translate it to English. Not Google translator version, but sth poetic.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be helpful if you at least attempted a translation of your own.

Answer (score 1):

Literature could dissolve all the unfriendly

But he never be treated kindly

Someone hurt him time to time

He couldn't bear it even once

Answer (score 1):

Literature, be my stepping bridge,

To fill a yawning gap;

But all it has to teach,

Is lift a knife to stab.

Answer (score 1):

I like how you think Wayne! I'm just not poetic enough!

我以为文学可以踏过所有误解和隔阂,
I (always) believed that literature could overcome all misunderstandings and estrangements,
没想过会有人冲它不止一次举起刀。
I never thought there might be those who rail against it.

The world is proof positive that literature cannot achieve the above mentioned! \

Comment: Thanks Pedroski. I took a ton of "poetic" liberties with that dark interpretation of that enigmatic passage. I admit I was taken aback when I read 冲它不止一次举起刀 and saw how it could be interpreted either way. As it turned out you took the literal way as opposed to my "poetic" way. Glad that this Thread is not closed as it does have some saving grace.

Answer (score 0):

I thought literature could overcome all misunderstandings and gaps, and I never thought anyone would raise it at it more than once.

You can download this Chinese English translator app because I find its translation very accurate and it can translate simplified or traditional Chinese into English. [Link download app](https://hanzii.page.link/download-android-1)

[image]